# return the sum of the strings where a letter is present - using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List with words (programming languages), and I want to figure out which letter in the alphabet is present in these words and then sum the total string length of these words, and in the end return the one letter which returns the longest string matching these words. Here's what I've got until now, and I'm pretty much not getting further.

This is an exercise in me trying to understand java streams better.

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void argh() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("java");
        list.add("php");
        list.add("python");
        list.add("perl");
        list.add("c");
        list.add("lisp");
        list.add("c#");

        Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> list.stream();
        IntStream.range('a', 'z').forEach(i -> {
                int strlen = streamSupplier.get()
                    .filter(k -> {
                            char ch = (char) i;
                            return k.contains("" + ch);
                        }
                    )
                    .map(s -> s.length())
                    .mapToInt(Integer::new)
                    .sum();
                System.out.println((char) i + " : " + strlen);
            }
        );
   }
}
```

The final output (result) I would expect is just something like 
"p : 17"

As the character 'p' is present in the words php, python, perl, lisp it sums those words and returns stringlength of 17.

Preferably in a

```
map<String,int> with the size of 1
```

or something, containing only the longest string.

Here's some pseudo code as to how I would have written it in 'plain' java:

```
int previousSum = 0;
for (string ch in ('a' to 'z') ) {
    int stringlengthSum =     findallMatchesInListandSumStringlength(stringlist,ch);
if (stringlengthSum > previousSum) {
    previousSum = stringLengthSum;
    longestCharacter = ch;
}
}
System.out.println("The longest sum is: " + previousSum + " by the character: " + longestcharacter);
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Can you describe result you want to receive for this concrete example? It  is not quite clear what you want to do.

Comment: looks good to me, what's your question? maybe this is better suited for CodeReview?

Comment: I don't want all of them, I just want the longest. Preferably in a Map<String,Integer> or something similar.

I'm just trying to wrap my brains around stream()-api  and trying to 'out brain' myself to strange and bizarre examples so that I might get a better grasp.

Comment: @Holger: Thank you, I saw that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to slightly change and optimize your code. Final solution will be:

```
Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> max = IntStream.range('a', 'z').boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> list.stream()
        .filter(k -> k.contains("" + (char) i.intValue()))
        .map(String::length)
        .mapToInt(Integer::new)
        .sum()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max((e1, e2) -> e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue())).get();

System.out.println((char)max.getKey().intValue() + ":" + max.getValue());
```

Changes are:

1) convert `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>` for being able collect map from it

2) collect pairs: int value of symbol -> sum of words with this symbol

and at least 3) find map entry with maximum element in it

Comment: apparently I can do this, according to IntelliJ:

".max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)).get();"

Thank you!

Comment: If you care for performance, you might replace `.filter(k -> k.contains(""+(char)i.intValue()))` with `.filter(k -> k.indexOf(i)>=0)` and `.map(String::length).mapToInt(Integer::new)` with `.mapToInt(String::length)`. Note that the more efficient alternatives are even simpler. And `.max((e1, e2) -> e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue()))` can be simplified to `.max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())`.

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, you're basically just missing the ordering of the stream.

To make the whole ordering a little easier, you can create a dedicated class:

```
class CharacterLengthSumResult implements Comparable<CharacterLengthSumResult> {
        final char c;
        final int sum;

        CharacterLengthSumResult(char c, int sum) {
            this.c = c;
            this.sum = sum;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(CharacterLengthSumResult o) {
            return Integer.compare(o.sum, sum);
        }
    }
```

Then the streaming logic becomes:

```
Optional<CharacterLengthSumResult> first = IntStream.range('a', 'z').mapToObj(i -> {
            String c = ((char) i) + "";
            int sum = list.stream().filter(s -> s.contains(c)).mapToInt(String::length).sum();
            return new CharacterLengthSumResult((char)i, sum);
        }).sorted().findFirst();

        if (first.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(first.get().c + " -> " + first.get().sum);
        }
```

If you want the whole thing as a map, you can extend the sorted with a collector:

```
...sorted().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.c, s -> s.sum));
```

Comment: Hm... looks like overcomplicated

Comment: @Andremoniy hm looks like clean code instead of hacking on map entries.

Comment: *hacking on map entries*??? :))) hahaha where do you see hacking? If you don't know how to cook stream, it doesn't mean that it is "hacking" :) Sorry